# Firmar xml con php y javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Mi problema es que quiero firmar un documento xml con php y firma .p12 al momento de validarlo en web server del SRI me arroja firma invalida, lo que puedo observar es que el SerialNumber siendo 9966979309424828163699019983 me muestra 9.966979309424828e+27 esto verifiqué después de firmar con otro sistema.

Podrían ayudarme a identificar el problema, gracias desde ya por la ayuda. Acá dejo el javascript que genera el firmado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//Serial Number
var X509SerialNumber = parseInt(cert.serialNumber, 16);





  function firmarComprobante(mi_contenido_p12, mi_pwd_p12, comprobante) {
  var arrayUint8 = new Uint8Array(mi_contenido_p12);
  var p12B64 = forge.util.binary.base64.encode(arrayUint8);
  var p12Der = forge.util.decode64(p12B64);
  var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12Der);

  var p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, mi_pwd_p12);

  var certBags = p12.getBags({bagType:forge.pki.oids.certBag})
  var cert = certBags[forge.oids.certBag][0].cert;
  var pkcs8bags = p12.getBags({bagType:forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag});
  var pkcs8 = pkcs8bags[forge.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag][0];
  var key = pkcs8.key;

  if( key == null ) {
   key = pkcs8.asn1;
  }

  certificateX509_pem = forge.pki.certificateToPem(cert);

  certificateX509 = certificateX509_pem;
  certificateX509 = certificateX509.substr( certificateX509.indexOf('\n') );
  certificateX509 = certificateX509.substr( 0, certificateX509.indexOf('\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----') );

  certificateX509 = certificateX509.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').replace(/([^\0]{76})/g, '$1\n');

  //Pasar certificado a formato DER y sacar su hash:
  certificateX509_asn1 = forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert);
  certificateX509_der = forge.asn1.toDer(certificateX509_asn1).getBytes();
  certificateX509_der_hash = sha1_base64(certificateX509_der);

   //Serial Number
   var X509SerialNumber = parseInt(cert.serialNumber, 16);

   exponent = hexToBase64(key.e.data[0].toString(16));
   modulus = bigint2base64(key.n);


   var sha1_comprobante = sha1_base64(comprobante.replace('<?xml
```

version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n', ''));

```
  var xmlns = 'xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"';


  //numeros involucrados en los hash:

 //var Certificate_number = 1217155;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //1562780 en el ejemplo del SRI
 var Certificate_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //1562780 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var Signature_number = 1021879;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //620397 en el ejemplo del SRI
 var Signature_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //620397 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var SignedProperties_number = 1006287;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //24123 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignedProperties_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //24123 en el ejemplo del SRI

//numeros fuera de los hash:

//var SignedInfo_number = 696603;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //814463 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignedInfo_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //814463 en el ejemplo del SRI
```

//var SignedPropertiesID_number = 77625;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //157683 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignedPropertiesID_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //157683 en el ejemplo del SRI

```
//var Reference_ID_number = 235824;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //363558 en el ejemplo del SRI
var Reference_ID_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //363558 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var SignatureValue_number = 844709;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //398963 en el ejemplo del SRI
var SignatureValue_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //398963 en el ejemplo del SRI

//var Object_number = 621794;//p_obtener_aleatorio(); //231987 en el ejemplo del SRI
var Object_number = p_obtener_aleatorio(); //231987 en el ejemplo del SRI
```

Comment: si quieres hacer la firma con php. porque solo pones medio codigo de javascript?

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y añadir en modo texto el código JS y PHP más relevante? Parece que estés perdiendo precisión al tratarlo como entero cuando haces ese parseInt, la solución podría ser tratarlo como string o como algún tipo de bigdecimal, pero para eso habría que ver más código.

Comment: queria poner todo el js que es el que firma el documento pero no me permite me podrias ayudar con algun contacto para pasarte el js

Comment: No hace falta todo el JS ni todo el PHP, solo hace las partes más importantes para poder ver el problema. Si hiciese falta más ya te irían preguntando más cosas.

Comment: ya e publicado el js sialguien me puede ayudar mil gracias

Comment: Si usas `parseInt()` considera el valor de `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`